# How to assign an id to a group SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, database-design, schema

I am running a scheduled task which checks the value of an attribute at a set time every night. My plan is to build up a frontend based on the values returned.

At the moment, I am returning over 800 rows in my database a night since there is such an amount of data to return.

One of these columns is the date that the query was ran on - it's struck me that this is redundant since, for every group of attributes (ie every night the scheduled task is ran) this dateTime value will be the same.

What's the best approach to remove this redundant/repeated date from my database?

At the moment I have colmn headings of :

```
Id -- Name -- AttributeIMeasure -- dateRan
```

Thanks for the help!

Comment: What are you doing with the data returned from the query? Are you storing it back in the database, write it to a file, or do something similar?

Comment: The data returned from the query makes up the data stored in Name and AttributeIMeasure. So I'm copying it from one database to another (the database I am copying from is dynamic and I wish to track it over time).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'd be tempted to create a separate table, `RunInformation`, with a primary key column, `Id`, and a `RunDate` column:

```
Id -- RunDate
```

You could then replace the `dateRan` column from your table with a reference to the `RunInformation` table. This will allow you to store additional information about the run in future, if the needs arises.

```
Id -- Name -- AttributeIMeasure -- RunInformationId
```

Comment: I see, but this would not reduce on redundant data stored, would it? Since, on a given day, every run of my query will return a list of rows with Name and AttributeIMeasure, but for all of rows returned, the RunDate will be the same! :)

Comment: Ahh I see what you mean now. This would reduce any redundancies. What kind of reference should I add to the RunInformation table ?

Comment: You should add 'RunInformationId' as a foreign key in your existing table.

Comment: If the issue is to save space, be careful not to use an INT for the ID's.  That's the same amount of space as a SMALLDATETIME.  You're forced to use a SMALLINT or TINYINT for the RunID to save space, and even then it will be so small as to be insignificant.

Answer (score 2):

I wouldn't remove this redundancy.

Can you be *certain* that you won't ever only update a *part* of a group?
- A failure or error of some kind?
- A change to the requirements in the future?

Also, what is the real down-side of the redundancy?  What actual *issue* are you trying to resolve?

If you do *really* need to do this, then you simply need a way of mapping attributes to groups.

Create an `attribute_groups` table (with id and dateRan fields as a minimum), and add an `attributeGroupID` field to the original table.

But I still do not see how the increase in schema complexity, additional join needed to get the DateRan value, and increased constraints, are worth it in this case.

Comment: Thanks for the response. I wish to build up a front end based on the values I have stored in my database. It will be running nightly for probably the next couple of years, returning ~800 results a night. All of this data is needed, except for the dateTime. I have very little experience in large scale programming of this nature, but I was assuming that, with all the data being stored, that it would be important if I could remove one column from every piece of data if possible :)

Comment: I would caution you against worrying about storage like this. It's probably not worth being concerned about space and efficiency at such a small scale. Unless you scale it up to millions of records the space difference will be negligible.

Comment: @SimonKiely - Also, you're not going to save much space.  Every record will need the new attributeGroupID field, then you have the space for the new table.  SMALLDATETIME on it's own is only 4 bytes, the same as an INT.  You're only going to save space using a SMALLINT for the groupID, and even then it's going to be a tiny amount.